# Adding Sidebar Full width header and footer

Tags: html, css

I found this full width html template and I would like to add a right sidebar between the header and footer to the template.

If somebody has a different code for a similar template, that would help too.

I'm not a developer (learning). I appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Layout</title>
<style media="all">
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: #e7e7e7;}
.header-outer, .content-outer, .footer-outer {width: 100%;}
.header-outer, .footer-outer {background: #c7c7c7;}
.header, .content, .footer {margin: 0 auto;}
.header, .footer {min-height: 100px; color: white; padding: 20px 0; width: 960px;}
.content {background: white; min-height: 400px; padding: 20px; width: 920px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header-outer">
<div class="header">
    <h1>Heading text</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-outer">
<div class="content">
    <p>Body text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer-outer">
<div class="footer">
    <p>Footer text</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples if you do a quick Google search or search on this site. There are a lot of suggestions that can be provided looking at your code, like creating a seperate css file and link it via HTML. This allows for easier reading and writing of code.

Answering your question in the most siplistic way, you can do that by doing the following:

### CSS

```
.sidebar {padding: 20px; float: right; min-height: 400px; background-color: #CCCCCC;}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
<p>Side Bar </p>
```

Comment: Jesse, the sidebar is way too far right. I would like to have it center next to the content (inside the 920px). I did Google search and the code above was the closest "full width header-footer with center content" sample I found. If you could please help me with the code or send me a link of a better code, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic layout with a sidebar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Layout</title>
<style media="all">
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: #e7e7e7;}
.header-outer, .footer-outer {width: 100%;}
.header-outer, .footer-outer {background: #c7c7c7;}
.header, .content, .footer {margin: 0 auto !important;}
.header, .footer {min-height: 100px; color: white; padding: 20px 0; width: 860px;}
.content {background: white; min-height: 400px; padding: 20px; width: 720px;}
.sidebar {background: white; min-height: 400px; padding: 20px; width: 200px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header-outer">
<div class="header">
    <h1>Heading text</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-outer">
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Body text</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <p>Sidebar text</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<center>
</div>

<div class="footer-outer">
<div class="footer">
    <p>Footer text</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After adding lots of text to the content div, the sidebar moved down. Is there anyway to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What did you put in the content section? Probably an element in there caused an issue.

Comment: I just added lots of paragraphs <p>Body text</> under the <div class="content"> and the sidebar moved down

Comment: I found this similar layout http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/layout-full-width-bands. Thank you!